# objective c import once

Tags: objective-c, import

I have a header file with a bunch on statics like

static NSString * SOME_NAME = @"someMeaning";

What is the best way to import this? Should I define them some other way?

I tried just using the #import statement but any file that imports it gives me a warning saying SOME_NAME defined but not used...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try declaring it in the header file as

```
extern NSString * const SOME_NAME;
```

And defining it in some implementation file as

```
NSString * const SOME_NAME = @"SOME_NAME"
```

The position of the const keyword is important, because that is what makes the pointer itself a constant.

Answer (score 0):

That's a warning, not an error. It's here to help you find variables you don't need anymore. But that kind of variables should be declared as extern, IMHO.

Comment: I am trying to keep it all in one file. If I declare it as extern I have a file looking like:

extern NSString * SOME_NAME;
extern NSString * SOME_NAME = @"someMeaning";

kind of weird, right? Or, is there another way?